# How to calculate the token price of already deployed ERC20 tokens

Tags: ether, erc-20

I am creating a smart contract, so inside that I have to pass the token in contract and the value of ether will be calculate on behalf of token price please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can only set the price of a token during its initial distribution phase (e.g. the crowdsale, ICO, etc.). Once the tokens have been initially sold, and they are out in the real world, then the price is set by supply and demand; you have no control.

If you are currently writing your token distribution contract (this is separate to the ERC-20 contract itself), then you can set the price there. Have a look at [these](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/crowdsale) (OpenZeppelin) example contracts.

However, your question is a bit ambiguous. If you've already distributed your tokens, then you won't be able to set the price. If you've published the ERC-20 contract but haven't distributed the tokens, then you should still be able to run your distribution phase using your distribution contract.

Comment: i want to make crypto to crypto smart contract where i need to sell erc20 token and on buyer side i need to calculate the price which i have to send to seller can you please describe the calculation because i have a price of token.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is impossible, because the price is determined by traders on exchanges.

Comment: but if i have token price than?

Comment: u can't get data like this: uint public price = 'some.api/price', u have to pass price everytime when u need: function funcWhereYouNeedPrice(uint memory _price) onlyOwner external { "operations with _price" }

Comment: but this is bad idea too, because u need to wait when transaction will be mined and price can be changed. so u will get not actual price. don't use this in financial operations

Comment: so what is the correct way to buy token behalf of eth? because i want to make crypto to crypto smart contract where i need to sell erc20 token and on buyer side i need to claculate the price which i have to send to seller.